# Running Unreal Build Tool with CreateProcess vs command line

Tags: c++, windows, tools

I'm working on a tool that generates some files for Unreal Projects. The only thing is if I try to get it to compile the project through CreateProcess the command doesn't run the same as the command line. I just get an error message from UBT about rule files not existing.

Command being run from CreateProcess:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

CreateProcess("C:/path/to/UnrealBuildTool.exe",
       "ProjectEditor Win64 Development C:/path/to/project.uproject -waitmutex -Deploy",
            NULL,
            NULL,
            FALSE,
            0,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            &si,
            &pi
        );
WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

In the command line `C:\path\to\UnrealBuildTool.exe ProjectEditor Win64 Development C:\path\to\project.uproject -waitmutext -Deploy` successfully compiles the project from any directory. Is there any other variables I need to pass into CreateProcess to get this command to run?

EDIT: Adding space to the start of the argument string fixed the issue. Is there any reason why Windows would need that space?

Comment: The code provided won't run because the first argument is not a string and the second argument is using backslashes that result in escape sequence characters rather than slashes.

Comment: @pharap I updated it so the path and strings are correct in the examples. That's what it is in my actual code. 

I had to add a space to the start of the argument string for everything to get detected correctly. Is that an issue with Windows or how UBT handles arguments? 

I have another CreateProcess call for generating project files, but that runs without any issues, whether I place a space at the start or end of the argument.

Comment: UnrealBuildToot.exe ?

Comment: @JonS That was a typo. I got it working. There's still the issue that I have to add a space to the start of the argument for a compilation to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're not *actually* passing the project ("ProjectEditor") to UnrealBuildTool when you invoke it via `CreateProcess`, which causes it to not build anything.

The first argument of a Windows command-line should be the name of the process or executable being invoked. `CreateProcess` does not join the process name you specify to the front of the command-line you specify. You need to do that yourself.

UnrealBuildTool is a C# application. The .NET runtime takes this first space-delimited argument and stores it elsewhere, passing the subsequent arguments to the `Main()` function of UnrealBuildTool, so the first argument *it* sees is "Win64." That's why when you add a space in front of your project name, you "fix" it. You've changed it so that the first space-delimited argument is an empty string.

You can verify this by writing a simple C# program that just prints all the arguments supplied to main, and trying to invoke it similarly. Using a tool like [Process Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Explorer) would also let you examine the actual command lines for the processes and see how they differ.

A more correct solution would be to call `CreateProcess` like this:

```
CreateProcess("C:/path/to/UnrealBuildTool.exe",
              "C:/path/to/UnrealBuildTool.exe ProjectEditor ..etc...",
              ...);
```

Comment: Alright, so it can be treated similarly to the family of `exec` functions.